# Oracle Apex Rows Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I needed help in Oracle apex 5.1 version.
I am trying to make changes in interactive report and when i do any editing in the  page it  redirects
to the first set of rows although i have applied changes in row 4. How to keep the page hold for it.

Example-

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1     a     b
2     c     d
          1 - 2 of 32 >

Col1 Col2 Col3
3     e     f
4     g     h
          3 - 4 of 32 >
```

Now if i apply change in 3 row-

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
3     e     xx
4     g     h
            3 - 4 of 32 >
```

and i press apply changes one button in my page it redirects to first set of rows and i have to navigate to the next set of rows to see the applied changes.
How to make that set of row on hold after clicking 'apply changes'.

Please help me achieve this.

Comment: When the user presses apply changes, how are you redirecting them back to the page? Is there an explicit branch?

Answer (score 0):

See this solution from Tom Petrus
https://github.com/tompetrus/oracle-apex-ir-refresh-pagination